# Calculate multiple bands average raster in QGIS with high number of bands

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, average

I am a new user of raster layers in QGIS.

I need to generate a new raster file with the average value for each pixel, from a raster file with 600 bands. The average has to be calculated from all the 600 bands, for each pixel.

The Raster Calculator only allows to add one band at a time, that would mean too much time and a risky process, considering that I have several similar raster layers that I have to work with.

Is there a way to add multiple bands at the same time in Raster Calculator in order to calculate it? Otherwise, is there another way to do it?

I tried also with RASS r.series but the output does not seem to be what I need, the layer is not shown in the canvas and the values are not what I expect to be (the data is about temperature)

[image: min and max layer values]

Answer (score 3):

In case someone faces the same situation, I solved it generating the calculation expression with Excel and Word. 
I had to make a sum of each of 600 bands from the same layer. First, with Excel:

Column A: make 600 rows with the same layer name.

Column B: make a column with the band's numbers  (from 1 to 600)

Column C: Concatenate columns A and B

[image]

The **"** symbol at the beginning and the **@** at the end of the layer name, as well as the **"** and **+** symbols at the end of the concat function are necessary in order to identifying the bands and summing them, in Qgis.

Then, in Word

1) Paste the generated rows in a new document

2) Search and replace the full stops after each band with a space or with nothing.

3) Delete the last **+** symbol in the last band.

Back In Qgis Raster Calculator, paste the whole expression.

Comment: I correct myself, there is no need to do the Word steps. You can paste directly the Excell cells from the CONCAT column to the raster calculator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python to build the expression. This should work for any number of bands:

```py
rasterlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('infra-red')[0] #Change infra-red to the name of your layer
bandcount = rasterlayer.bandCount() #Count the bands

tempexp = ['"{0}@{1}"'.format(rasterlayer.name(), bandnum) for bandnum in range(1,bandcount+1)] #['"infra-red@1"', '"infra-red@2"', '"infra-red@3"', '"infra-red@4"']
tempexp = '+'.join(tempexp) #'"infra-red@1"+"infra-red@2"+"infra-red@3"+"infra-red@4"'
exp = '('+tempexp+')/{0}'.format(bandcount) #'("infra-red@1"+"infra-red@2"+"infra-red@3"+"infra-red@4")/4'

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator", 
    {'EXPRESSION':exp,'LAYERS':[rasterlayer.source()],'CELLSIZE':None,'EXTENT':None,'CRS':None,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]